# 2-way communication from Unidata to MySQL

Tags: mysql, unidata

A customer has an application that stores a large amount of data in a Unidata database. This data is copied daily to a MySQL database. Can someone point me in the right direction to get the data to sync both ways? We need to be able to update the MySQL database with a custom application and have the data transferred back to the Unidata database for the main application. I've researched and read as much as I can find and cannot find much information on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will somewhat tough to do, without some kind of explicit code that's aware of what the data means and how to reconcile conflicts.  It's hard enough to do between two databases of the same kind, let alone one relational system and one non-relational.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135423/best-practice-patterns-for-two-way-data-synchronisation

http://docs.rocketsoftware.com/nxt/gateway.dll/RKBnew20/unidata/v7.3.7/unidata_vsgschemaapiuserguide_v737.pdf has information about how to make your unidata database accessible in a somewhat relational way, but it's a lot of work to setup.

I have two proposed approaches/answers:

1) If you have folks that understand the MySQL side and folks that know Unidata, have the MySQL side create an extract, move that over and write some UniBasic code to intelligently merge the data.

2) If you are lucky enough to have someone that understands both sides, and they can program in Java/DotNet, create a program that queries the MySQL side and inserts/updates in UniObjects on the fly (again I would call some UniBasic code to do that, but that's just my bias).

Neither of these are particularly "easy" either, but I have done both and they definitely work.  Option 1 is the brute force approach and what I would do if it were my problem.